# Twig: How to print special symbols, such as Copyright, Trademark, etc

Tags: twig, symbols

I want to use special symbols, but instead all I get printed question mark symbol �

I tried

```
{% autoescape 'html' %}
    {{ '©'|escape('html') }}   {# won't be double-escaped #}
    {{ '©'|escape(strategy) }} {# will be double-escaped #}
{% endautoescape %}
```

and it did not work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use raw filter :

```
{{ '©'|raw }}
```

http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/raw.html

If the output is supposed to be HTML, you can also use HTML entity notation, for example trademark sign:

```
{{ '&#8482;' }}
```

or email sign:

```
{{ '&#64;' }}
```

Comment: `{{ '©'|raw }}` did not work. Using the copyright [character-code](http://character-code.com/) `{{ '&#169;' }}` worked, merci.

Answer (score -1):

Since you want to display a static string and not a variable, you can write the character directly, you don't need to use the `{{ }}` tag:

```
©
```

Or by using the HTML entity cited by Miro:

```
&#8482;
```